# A font that covers the UTF-8 encoding entirely?

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm a programmer and for some testing I need a font that covers all the glyphs and the characters encoded by the UTF8 standard.

I personally can't remember or find anything like that, I hope you can name a font that will meet my requirement.

Comment: It's a long shot, but do the characters have to be visible? http://blog.typekit.com/2013/03/28/introducing-adobe-blank/

Comment: @Brendan yes, because I need some kind of visual feedback

Answer (score 2):

I won't act like I found this myself...[this answer over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8451615/945370) points out that while covering every code point is unfeasible, a commenter references [Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html), which is lo-fi but should serve your purposes pretty well.

Comment: I was hoping for some scalable format, but at least this will print something useful, thanks, let's see if someone will post anything other than this GNU font.

Comment: @user2485710  you could generate one.

Answer (score 1):

In utf-8 is 4195456 symbols. In new standard Unicode compatible. For 1,2 3 and 4 octets. As to 5 and 6 octets it gives 2218787968 symbols. Is much more than standard Unicode. More over even 4 octets is more. Not all symbols is represented...I suspect is restricted only first 65535 symbols as is in Unicode. So utf-8 fonts is not full...

Comment: This is essentially  the correct answer, if you know the answer. Too bad the language is so weirdly written that its hard  to understand. Could you please edit this. To summarize for others UTF-8 has 4195456 possible characters while the maximum number of glyphs is 65535 so clearly one can not fit the characters in the font. Offourse if you use a different font tech you could.